# PayPal Payment Experience Profile creation

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

This uses a sandbox ClientID and secret obtained from a PayPal REST app, to obtain an oauth2 token

```
curl -v https://$url/v1/oauth2/token \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
   -u "${client_id}:${secret_id}" \
   -d "grant_type=client_credentials" 2>/dev/null > /tmp/output$$

access_token=`cat /tmp/output$$ | jq .access_token | sed -e "s+\"++g"`
app_id=`cat /tmp/output$$ | jq .app_id | sed -e "s+\"++g"`
```

This is the final curl which fails:

```
curl -v -X GET https://$url/v1/payment-experience/web-profiles  -H "Content-Type:   
    application/json"  -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"
```

gives

```
[]

curl -v -X GET https://$url/v1/payment-experience/web-profiles/XYZ  -H "Content-Type: 
    application/json"  -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"
```

If XYZ (Profile ID) is required after URL in last curl above, then where do I obtain XYZ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you need a web experience profile for? That is something old.  I recommend looking at the newest v2/checkout/orders APIs, and not using the old v1/payments API for anything at all.

---

But if on consideration you find you have a real need to create a web experience profile, you need to provide the necessary parameters on creation. Here is an example:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payment-experience/#example

An identifier ("XYZ" as you call it) in the URL is not required for creation; this identifies a web experience profile and would be returned to you on successful creation